# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException error and im unsure how to fix it

Tags: java

I keep getting an error with my code and I'm not sure how to fix it. The top portion is the error I'm receiving.

the objective of this program is to input a text file and format it into rows and columns.

This file contains Student names and 3 scores for each

Sample Input file:
Andy Borders
200
250
400
John Smith
120
220
330

I'm by no means asking for anyone to do it for me, I'm just new and unsure how to fix this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Project_5.main(Project_5.
```

-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Project_5
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    String fileName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("%s"+"%20s"+"%10s"+"%10s"+"%10s","Name","Score1","Score2","Score3");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String Name = inputFile.nextLine();
            int Score1 = inputFile.nextInt();
            int Score2 = inputFile.nextInt();
            int Score3 = inputFile.nextInt();

            System.out.printf("%s"+"%9s"+"%10s"+"%10s",Name,Score1,Score2,Score3);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        inputFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(
            "There was a problem reading from " + fileName);
    }
        finally {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Your question is tagged `compiler-errors` but if it's an exception, it's happening at *execution* time, not compile-time.

Comment: @ashutosh the input is a text document that includes a students name, and the 3 test scores ( Andy Borders, 200, 250, 400 )

Comment: Is the error happening at the while loop, where the data in the file may not follow the order of nextLine -> nextInt -> nextInt -> nextInt?

Comment: is there a way to attach the text document that's being inputted??

Comment: You can just write 2-3 sample input lines in your question.

Comment: the error occurs after 'System.out.printf("%s"+"%9s"+"%10s"+"%10s",Name,Score1,Score2,Score3);' it prints out the first students 3rd score and then fails

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with String Name = inputFile.nextLine() for the second student.

Comment: If your loop reaches the statement `Name = inputFile.nextLine();` a second time, then it doesn't read the students name. See the above link to know why.

Comment: thanks @Tom I added a blank ' inputFile.nextLine(); ' after ' int Score3 = inputFile.nextInt(); ' and it worked. as discussed in the post you attached

Comment: Nice to hear. If I remember correctly you can accept the vote for a duplicate question, if you like. Also try to understand why it helped here. Then you can avoid similar problems in the future :).

Comment: I did that.. thanks a lot!